# Why does appending a list to a list not work where appending a list created from the elements of that list does?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a function that returns a list of lists where the lists have two elements: the start and end of a region of an input list. I have a temporary variable that I append to my output list but was surprised that it changed the whole list each time it was appended. It feels like I must not understand something fundamental to Python lists for this to be true. When I append *[pair[0], pair[1]]* on line 31, however, it works where just appending *pair* does not. Sample code and output is below. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

```
# Returns list of list indexes with the start and stop index for each flat part of the signal (ignoring the ramps in between)
def edge_detect(input: list, edge: float = 0.5, filter_limit: int = 5) -> list:
    last = None
    index = 0
    output_wrong = []
    output_right = []
    pair = [0,0]
    filter_count = 0
    finding = "start"
    for value in input:
        if finding == "start":
            if last == None:
                pair[0] = index
            else:
                # If this point is too different from the last then last wasn't the start of a flat region.
                if abs(value - last) > edge:
                    pair[0] = index
                # If this point has settles then last could be the start of a flat region but wait for filter_limit before deciding that 
                elif filter_count < filter_limit:
                    filter_count += 1
                # Point has settled for filter limit. Start looking for the "stop" point 
                else:
                    finding = "stop"
                    pair[1] = index
        elif finding == "stop":
            # As soon as value falls outside of flat region record that region and start looking for another flat spot
            if abs(value - last) > edge:
                finding = "start"
                filter_count = 0
                output_wrong.append(pair)
                output_right.append([pair[0], pair[1]])
            else:
                pair[1] = index

        last = value
        index += 1
    return output_wrong, output_right

test = [0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    
        1,    2.1,    3.3,    4.6,    6,    7.5,    9.1,    10.8,    12.6,    
        14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    14.5,    
        17.5,    20.6,    23.8,    27.1,    30.5,    34,    37.6,    41.3,    45.1,    
        49,    49,    49,    49,    49,    49,    49,    49,    49,    49,    49,    
        54,    59.1,    64.3,    69.6,    75,    80.5,    86.1,    91.8,    97.6,    
        103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    103.5,    
        110.5,    117.6,    124.8,    132.1,    139.5,    147,    154.6,    162.3,    170.1,    
        178,    178,    178,    178,    178,    178,    178,    178,    178,    178,    178,    
        187,    196.1,    205.3,    214.6,    224,    233.5,    243.1,    252.8,    262.6,    272.5]

steps_wrong, steps_right = edge_detect(test)
print(steps_wrong)
print(steps_right)

step_data = []
for step in steps_wrong:
    step_data.append(test[step[0]:step[1]])
print(step_data)

step_data = []
for step in steps_right:
    step_data.append(test[step[0]:step[1]])
print(step_data)
```

This is the sample output:

```
[[99, 89], [99, 89], [99, 89], [99, 89], [99, 89]]
[[0, 9], [19, 29], [39, 49], [59, 69], [79, 89]]
[[], [], [], [], []]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5], [49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49], [103.5, 103.5, 103.5, 103.5, 103.5, 103.5, 103.5, 103.5, 103.5, 103.5], [178, 178, 178, 178, 178, 178, 178, 178, 178, 178]]
```

Comment: By appending `pair` to `output_wrong`, you're adding multiple references to the same list, whose values keep getting changed. `output_right` gets a new list appended each time.

Comment: I really thought that when I was appending values to a list it was making copies of the values, not appending references that update. I wonder how many other places I've done this now that might be broken. It was like this in python 2 as well?

Comment: In Python 2.x, yes, even in Python 1.x. A list is sequence, which contains references to other objects. Appending a list to another list just adds a reference.

Comment: Huh...OK, I guess I learned something very important today. But if I append ints not lists it seems to behave how I had expected?